# Filling rows in Excel with alternating formulas referencing different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill the rows of an Excel sheet with alternating sheet references in each row. For example, row 9 references row 2 of sheet A, row 10 references row 9 of sheet B, row 11 references row 3 of sheet A, and row 12 references row 10 of sheet B. I've typed out this repeating formula for the first 6 rows, but when I try to use the autofill drag-down functionality it skips to row 8 of sheet A going in row 15 of the main sheet. Is there a way around this so I can avoid typing out 500 lines of formulas?

The two alternating references are `"='Gamma to Z'!E2"` and `"='LPD'!D9"`, and these have their own dependencies within their respective sheets.

Comment: could you add the actual two formulas?

Comment: @ScottCraner added thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(9:9)),INDEX('LPD'!D:D,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+9),INDEX('Gamma to Z'!E:E,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+2))
```

Comment: Works for the first sheet row references! I should be able to modify it myself to work for the second one as well, hopefully. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

A VBA loop can do that for you:

```
For i = 1 to 250
    Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("A" & i * 2).formula = "='Gamma to Z'!E" & i + 1
    Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("A" & i * 2 + 1).formula = "='LPD'!D" & i + 8
Next i
```